# Javascript Issue with Ajax reloading grid

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have this script in the  tag that's making the header row in the grid frozen.
It's working good, but after I add a row to the grid with Ajax, the row goes back to regular mode, and it's not frozen anymore.
What am I missing?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=gvPayments.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 500
        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I believe the problem is $(document).ready() isn’t called after an asynchronous postback, so I suggest you have a look at this page:

http://web.archive.org/web/20101109152029/http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/02/24/jQuery-document-ready-and-ASP-NET-Ajax-asynchronous-postback.aspx